# Aggregate key column and multiple value columns to JSON object

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL,
    key text NOT NULL,
    x int NOT NULL,
    y int NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (name, key)
);
```

With this data:

```
id                                   name key x y
12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789000 foo  a   1 2
12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789001 foo  b   3 4
12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789002 foo  c   5 6
12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789003 foo  d   7 8
12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789004 bar  v   0 0
12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789005 bar  w   1 1
12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789006 bar  z   2 2
12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789007 baz  a   8 7
12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789008 baz  b   6 5
12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789009 baz  c   4 3
12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789010 baz  d   2 1
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT name, json_build_object(key, json_build_object('x', x, 'y', y))
FROM my_table;
```

With this result:

```
name json_build_object
foo  {"a" : {"x" : 1, "y" : 2}}
foo  {"b" : {"x" : 3, "y" : 4}}
foo  {"c" : {"x" : 5, "y" : 6}}
foo  {"d" : {"x" : 7, "y" : 8}}
bar  {"v" : {"x" : 0, "y" : 0}}
bar  {"w" : {"x" : 1, "y" : 1}}
bar  {"z" : {"x" : 2, "y" : 2}}
baz  {"a" : {"x" : 8, "y" : 7}}
baz  {"b" : {"x" : 6, "y" : 5}}
baz  {"c" : {"x" : 4, "y" : 3}}
baz  {"d" : {"x" : 2, "y" : 1}}
```

What I'd like to have:

```
foo {"a" : {"x" : 1, "y" : 2}, "b" : {"x" : 3, "y" : 4}, "c" : {"x" : 5, "y" : 6}, "d" : {"x" : 7, "y" : 8}}
bar {"v" : {"x" : 0, "y" : 0}, "w" : {"x" : 1, "y" : 1}, "z" : {"x" : 2, "y" : 2}}
baz {"a" : {"x" : 8, "y" : 7}, "b" : {"x" : 6, "y" : 5}, "c" : {"x" : 4, "y" : 3}, "d" : {"x" : 2, "y" : 1}}
```

I know I need to `GROUP BY name` and [aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-aggregate.html) the other columns, but couldn't find a suitable combination of [`functions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html). Is this even possible with a single query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    json_object_agg(key, json_build_object('x', x, 'y', y)) 
FROM data
GROUP BY name
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9e88c7e81b1a83d71dffa3423fb4a281)

[`json_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) does exactly what you want.